# Redirect all http traffic to static address in OpenWrt on Raspberry

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iptables, raspberry-pi, openwrt

I have an ISP router with IP 192.168.1.254.

I installed OpenWrt on my Raspberry PI 3 B.

Raspberry is connected to the ISP router via ethernet

On the Raspberry I configured 2 networks:

1. wan
2. wifi

---

**WAN**

- DHCP client on the same ISP router network => can go on internet

**WIFI**

- static ip on a different subnet 192.168.2.1
- bridged network
- DHCP server enabled

---

**Firewall zone**

I associated the following firewall zone to the wifi network:

```
input: accept
output: accept
forward: accept
destination zone: wan
```

In this way if I connect to the wifi network with a client I receive a 192.168.2.* address, and this is what I desire.

The connected client can reach internet through wan network.

Now I want to intercept all the traffic coming from a client connected to the wifi network 192.168.2.* and redirect it to a static address.

I tried several things but I can't make it working.

What is the right way to try?

Comment: Intercept and redirect as in: *copy* to monitor traffic, or really *redirect* to use a kind of transparent man-in-the-middle proxy? Could you clarify this, ie in order to achieve what goal?

Comment: @A.B I really want to redirect traffic to reach a static address. I want to achieve that whatever address the user puts into its browser, the same page is served. E.g. user asks for www.google.it or www.apple.com or helloman.net but he receives only one page